# Sqoop import multiple tables but not all

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, data-ingestion

All the searches I've found show how to import one table or recommend the import-all-tables.  What if I want 35 of 440 tables from my db.  Can I just write one command and separate the tables by comma or do I have to put it in a script and copy and past the commands over and over and change the table name each time?

What I want to do:

```
echo "Sqoop Import"
--options-file ${path} 
--table tbl1,tbl2,tbl3\
--target-dir ${path}
--m 1\
```

What I fear I may have to do:

```
echo "Sqoop Import"
--options-file ${path} 
--table tbl1\
--target-dir ${path}
--m 1

wait 

echo "Sqoop Import"
--options-file ${path} 
--table tbl2\
--target-dir ${path}
--m 1
```

Comment: This will help you :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966626/how-to-import-the-data-from-multiple-source-thru-sqoop/34985029#34985029

Comment: @vinayak This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Good.Hope it solved the problem..Please upvote my answer.

Comment: @vinayak_narune can you post some text explaining the link and I will accept it as the answer.  hrobertv answer is not the best as per my comment I left.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a sqoop developer thought like you. :)

You can use import-all-tables.
And then add --exclude-tables   Comma separated list of tables to exclude from import process.

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1766722

Comment: You can also use the -m 1.  Guessing the table doesn't have a PK.

Comment: The only problem that I see and have with import-all-tables is that you cannot specify a schema.  It wants to bring in all the schemas and their tables.  At least I don't know of a way to specify a schema.  So I'm left doing what you are originally trying to avoid.  I have to list them out.

Comment: also with the answer you provided this is still going to be labour intensive as I have to specify the 405 tables I want to exclude...It would have been nice to have an option like --include-tables then list out the tables you want to include...

Answer (score 1):

Use `--exclude-tables "table1,table2"` option to ignore the table1 and table2.

Do **NOT** add white-space between the table names (aka. `"table1, table2"`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the apply the same command for Hive import as:

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
--connect jdbc:mysql://your_ip_address:3306/database_name \
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
--username root \
--warehouse-dir temp_dir_for_staging \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \
--hive-database hive_db \
--exclude-tables list_of_tables_to_be_excluded \
-m 1
```

Remember in Hive you need staging area.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop \
--username root \
--password hadoop \
--warehouse-dir /Sqoop21/AllTables \
--exclude-tables table1,tables2
```

Comment: When importing more than one table using `sqoop-import` command, isn't it a good practice / mandatory to use `--warehouse-dir` instead of `--target-dir` ?